# mvn install fails due to "incompatible types"

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm getting the following error from "mvn clean install"

`[ERROR]    /private/tmp/framework/src/main/java/org/jboss/narayana/txframework/api/annotation/transaction/WSBA.java:[21,65] incompatible types
found   : org.jboss.narayana.txframework.api.configuration.transaction.CompletionType
required: org.jboss.narayana.txframework.api.configuration.transaction.CompletionType
[ERROR] /private/tmp/framework/src/main/java/org/jboss/narayana/txframework/api/annotation/service/ServiceRequest.java:[32,56] incompatible types
found   : org.jboss.narayana.txframework.api.configuration.service.RequestType
required: org.jboss.narayana.txframework.api.configuration.service.RequestType
[INFO] 2 errors`

I'm assuming this is a dependency issue and there is another instance of CompletionType in the build path somewhere. I've checked this is not the case and also tried with an empty ~/.m2/repository.

I've tried renaming the package of the offending packages and this does not fix the problem. I simply get the same error with the new package name on both lines.

My dependencies in the pom.xml shouldn't be including a lib that has these classes in.

I've tried to reproduce this on another developer's computer and the problem does not occur.

I am seeing this problem on two of my computers. These computers have a lot of their environment synced, so it doesn't surprise me that the problem is also being synced. However on my office computer  I can do a successful "mvn install" within Intellij, but not on the command line. On my home computer I get this problem, both on the command line and within IntelliJ.

I've tried Googleing for this issue, but once I remove text specific to my project from the build, I don't have anything specific enough to search on.

The pom.xml can be found here:

http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbosstm/trunk/txframework/framework/pom.xml

Yes, I am aware that this is a JBoss package, in which the problem occurs. I work for JBoss and this is my code, so I can't get them to fix it ;-)

Thanks.

Comment: could you make a 'mvn dependency:tree' and post the result here?

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow btw. Also: forget the dependency tree, its most likely not helping here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in the annotation processing of the compiler in this version of the Oracle JDK:

`java version "1.6.0_27"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_27-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.2-b06, mixed mode)`

It also occurs in the equivalent mac version, which at the time of posting is the latest release.

I fixed the problem by switching to this release of OpenJDK:

`java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.4) (fedora-60.1.10.4.fc15-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)`

There are workarounds if you can't switch JDK (for example if you have a mac).

More details can be found on the bug report, that I am using to track this issue:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBTM-997

Comment: It seems the issue exists as well in this version: "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode). Fortunately I found this answer which led me in the right direction... Changing the java version to 1.6.0_26-b03 made my jenkins build pass again...

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I restructured this answer, because its primary purpose is to provide a solution to find the problem rather than solving it. The elements are added in the order I posted them in the comments or in here.

0. It is *not* a regular dependency problem, because that would go away if you change the name of your classes.
1. It could be related to the java version. Try setting source and target explicitly.
2. It can be a jar thats wrongly in your dependency structure, try this:
   add this to your pom:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>
                    ${project.build.directory}
                </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <version>4.0.0</version>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

call clean install and then try this command on your shell (in the base path of the project, NOT the dist dir.):

```
find . -name "*jar" -exec jar -tvf {} \; |grep RequestType
```

That way you see how many representations of RequestType are on your classpath maybe you see where the wrong one comes from.

3. Its possible that the right version of your class exists now, but that the class that originating the problem (ServiceRequest.java) compiles against the wrong one. Put them both in the same classpath, then try again.
4. Have you somewhere on your disk an old version of the class? Try removing it (by moving it on a portable device if you still need it).
5. Delete every binary in your classpath manually. Don't rely on 'mvn clean' to work.
6. Print out the classpath (google will tell you how) maven is using. Check that there is nothing on that you did not expect.
7. (Obscure) Its possible to create the very same directory twice by using the more obscure features of UTF. That would happen if your paths contain a non ASCII Character and one of your machines is a Mac (really, no joke. For german capable: http://www.danisch.de/blog/2011/11/18/wer-unicode-und-utf-erfunden-hat-gehort-erschlagen/).
8. Have you checked that your environment variables are set correctly? Double check them.
9. call:

   mvn clean
   mvn compile

then see how many instances of the offending classes you have.

Comment: thanks. please set the java version (see here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html ), its unset atm. ; I'll take a deeper look at the pom meanwhile.

Comment: minor: your pom says in the comments that the default will skip all tests but skip is false ;) other than that I could not find something strange in there. Could it be that there are more than one version of your file in the compilepath, maybe from older settings (did you ever change the build path?) - Have you deleted the class and jar files within the project scope manually (to be sure that clean did not overlook something?) (I have some more obscure ideas left so tell me if something worked yet)

Comment: I tried setting the java source and target versions to 1.6 after I posted this question. I still get the same error. Thanks for looking into this issue :-)

Comment: Just added some more info to the question: I am seeing this problem on two of my  computers. These computers have a lot of there environment synced, so it doesn't surprise me that the problem is also being synced. However on my office computer  I can do a successful "mvn install" within Intellij, but not on the command line. On my home computer I get this problem, both on the command line and within IntelliJ.

Comment: okay, the compiler message says there is another class with the same fqn on your classpath, so you might want to investigate what is on your classpath, try printing it (google tells you how) and then search to see where the class comes from. I would still assume that it either IS there (in an old separate file, most likely a jar, or as a link or whatever) OR is created while compiling twice (because it is in your resources path or something) -> although that would more likely produce a 'duplicate class' error. Are you using *nix?

Comment: @PaulRobinson I just added another suggestion in the answer above, have a look.

Comment: is there any place on your hard drive where an old version of this class still exists? If so -> Is it possible that this place is somewhere on your build path?

Comment: @PaulRobinson I had a bug in the find command, I just fixed it. Also I wrote down every guess I had in mind, I hope one helps.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm in the process of going through each of your suggestions.

Comment: you're welcome. (you know whats fascinating here? With short answers on easy questions I got a lot more reputation than on ones like this where I really invest time...) Anyway, its more fun to work on problems like this one.

Comment: sorry for the delay getting back to you. I tried switching compiler and the problem went away. It seems like this is a bug in the compiler. See my answer for more info. I agree with you, it's a shame that your effort on this question won't get the recognition it deserves; yet by answering many easy questions you get a disproportionate amount of recognition. I assume this would lead most people to just answer easy questions, leaving hard questions unanswered. This, of course is a downward spiral where the site tends towards only having trivial questions...

Comment: ... Anyway, I'll see what I can click on to, at least, give you some 'reputation'. Thanks a lot for the help! Keep up the good work!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't mark your answer as useful as I don't have a reputation of '15' yet. Maybe I can mark it as useful later when I get the required rep. I'll try not to forget. If you know of anything else I can do, let me know.

Comment: @PaulRobinson Thank you, I was just ranting. Its completely fine the way it is, because I don't think people here answer for the reputation but because its part of our culture. I'm glad you could overcome your problem and I will certainly remember the solution so the next time someone meets this problem I can just link them here :) Have fun and again, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning workspace also worked. :)